# ngStyle: Error saying "Missing expected }"

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm getting the following error from chrome console, when interpreting

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': '100%'; 'height': '100%'; 'background-size': 'cover'; 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'; 'border-radius': '0px';}"></div>
```

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Missing expected
>   } at column 17 in [{'width': '100%'; 'height': '100%';
>   'background-size': 'cover'; 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat';
>   'border-radius': '0px';}] in ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@31:29
>   ("="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

What's supposed to cause the error?

Comment: I guess `;` within the object literal should be instead `,`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This was obviously what I had to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike the `style` attribute which takes CSS styles, `ngStyle` takes a javascript object (represented in a string). That's why you have to wrap `100%` in quotes `'100%'`, as well as other attributes like `background-size` because `%` and `-` characters are illegal in javascript attribute names/values.

**CSS**

```
blah {
  attribute: value;
  attribute-dash: value;
}
```

**Object**

```
{
  attribute: value,
  'attribute-dash': value
}
```

Because of this, you need to replace the `;` with `,`.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', 'background-size': 'cover', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'border-radius': '0px'}"></div>
```

**NOTE:** `ngStyle` is supposed to be used if you have dynamic values you're trying to set. It allows you to pass variables into the styles as well as toggle specific styles using booleans. If you're just trying to set inline styles, you should use the normal `style` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In newer version you can also use unit.

> The key is a style name, with an optional . suffix (such as 'top.px', 'font-style.em').

Like

`[ngStyle]="{'width.px':200, 'height.px':200}"`